# How can I query all rows out of my table with GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

This is my users table:

| id | name | pass |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | 0a2f60e41b1d3d302c0af17bc65d4f48 |
| 2 | SecUsr | 40597ff5ca18da3a91e0ee330496bc77 |

How can I get all rows with GORM? If I use `db.Find()` method, I'll get only the first row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the find function in the following way

```
   var users []User
   // Get all records
   result := db.Find(&users)
   // SELECT * FROM users;
   result.RowsAffected // returns found records count, equals `len(users)`
   result.Error        // returns error
```

Comment: Thanks! For any cause I didn't notice that it is necessary to create an array